# Vuetify: Applying 'mt-32' Margin Utility Class Not Working as Expected

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm new to learning and using vuetify, in the following code I am trying to add mt-32 class to the v-form but it does not work

```
<template>
  <v-form class="mt-32">
    <v-container>
      <v-row align="center" justify="center">
        <RadioButton question_text="Your favourite search engine" />
      </v-row>
      <v-row align="center" justify="center">
        <v-col cols="12" md="6" xl="4">
          <SingleSelectForm />
        </v-col>
          <v-col cols="12" md="6" xl="4">
          <SingleSelectForm />
        </v-col>
      </v-row>
    </v-container>
  </v-form>
</template>
```

But when applying class="mt-16" for example, it works. Why?
While when applying mt-32 or mt-64 it does not work

In my case I want to implement this mt-32 class without writing style="margin-top:32px;"

Comment: `mt-32` doesn't exists like class in Vuetify. The latest class of margin is `mt-16`

Answer (score 0):

Vuetify spacing helper classes apply margin or padding to an element ranging from **0 to 16**

https://vuetifyjs.com/en/styles/spacing/#how-it-works